# How to upload file via FTP in CGI script?

Tags: perl, ftp, cgi

Please see the upload script below. It works, but what I want to do, is use the my FTP site for the **Upload_dir**, instead of the local directory of my website, which is hosted by my service provider.

Please suggest what I should do different to make this work! Thank you in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use File::Basename;
$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;
my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";
my $upload_dir = "MyWebsite/upload";
my $query = new CGI;
my $filename = $query->param("photo");
my $email_address = $query->param("email_address");
if ( !$filename ) { print $query->header ( );
print "There was a problem uploading your photo (try a smaller file).";
exit; } my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '\..*' );
$filename = $name . $extension;
$filename =~ tr/ /_/;
$filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;
if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ ) { $filename = $1;
} else { die "Filename contains invalid characters";
} my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo");
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";
binmode UPLOADFILE;
print $query->header();
while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
{
  print UPLOADFILE;
}
close UPLOADFILE;
print $query->header ( ); print qq~
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>
Thanks!
</title>
<style type="text/css"> img {border: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Thanks for uploading your photo!</p>
<p>Your email address: $email_address</p>
<p>Your photo:</p>
<p><img src="/upload/$filename" alt="Photo" /></p>
</body>
</html>
~;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest way is to upload to the local file like you are doing. Once the file is uploaded you should then add sime Net::FTP code to send the file from the webserver to your FTP server. Your service provider will need to allow outgoing FTP for this to work.

```
use Net::FTP;
...
close UPLOADFILE;
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new( $your_ftp )         || die "$@";
$ftp->login($ftp_user,$ftp_pswd)             || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->cwd($ftp_dir)                          || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->binary();
$ftp->pasv();   # optional. May be required
$ftp->put("$upload_dir/$filename",$filename) || die $ftp->message;
undef $ftp;
...
```

By the way I usually use an auto generated local filename to ensure two users uploading at the same time with the same name don't cause issues. I usually use something like `time().'-'.$$`